# Python Selenium Automation

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate downloading files from a website, and am having an issue with a list box contained on the page. Once I submit the form, a window pops up saying that I never selected the option value in the list box, i.e. the option value does not remain selected once I submit. Here is my code below. Any help? Please and thanks

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/has/HAS.FileAppRouter?datasetname=6500&subqueryby=STATION&applname=&outdest=FILE")
stations = Select (driver.find_element_by_name('stations'))
stations.select_by_value('KLWX')
#radar = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dataset-select')
radar = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dataset-select')
for x in range(0,len(radar)):
    if radar[x].is_displayed():
        radar[x].click()
select = Select (driver.find_element_by_name('begyear'))
select.select_by_value('2012')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('begmonth'))
select.select_by_visible_text('06') 
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('begday'))
select.select_by_visible_text('30')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('endyear'))
select.select_by_value('2012')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('endmonth'))
select.select_by_visible_text('07')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('endday'))
select.select_by_visible_text('01')
element = driver.find_element_by_name('emailadd')
element.send_keys("felisha.lawrence@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=submit]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just that you are clicking the wrong element - it should the `button`, not the `input`. Replace:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=submit]").click()
```

with:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type=submit]").click()
```